# Auto-incrementing column based on distinct values of two other columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I insert into a table I have two columns that are of importance, the foreign key column and the subset of that foreign key. For instance I may have the following key of 2432 with subsets of 1,2,3,4

```
2432   1   1
2432   1   2
2432   1   3
2432   1   4
2432   1   5
2432   1   6
2432   2   1
2432   2   2
2432   2   3
2432   3   1
2432   3   2
2432   3   3
2432   3   4
2432   3   5
2432   4   1
2432   4   2
```

The amount of subsets per key varies, I just need a way to create an increment value for each distinct key and subset that would result in the third column above. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (C1, C2, C3)
SELECT FKCol, FKSubsetCol,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FKCol, FKSubsetCol ORDER BY FKCol)
```